# Unable to run vitest in cicd in a vue3 project

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, vite, cicd, vitest

when i deploy my app using cicd and it comes to the stage of the test I use nom run test to use vitest and it doesn't work and the error message is "Error: required() of ES Module (and than the path to @vue/apollo-composable/dist in node_modules) not supported". my app using vite vue3 and apollo

Reproduction
the repo is confidential and for that reason i cant provide it. but the test stage looks like that:
test:
tags:

- $RUNNER_SITE
- $RUNNER_NAME
  stage: test
  image: node:16.14.2-alpine
  script:
- npm config set registry (and than path to the registry)
- npm set strict-ssl false
- npm ci
- npm run test

When I run the project locally and then run npm test it works but when I run it with the cicd it doesnt